# Need Help on Nested CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, case

I need to rewrite the following IF-THEN code in SQL, and below is my first attempt. But when I ran the SQL code, it returned an error message of : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. Could anyone please help?

And also, I am wondering if there is a better alternative way to rewrite the SAS code other than using a nested Case statement. I am a newbie to SQL. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

/************************** SAS code *************************** /

```
if Record_type = 'Cliam'and Claim_Type_E0141 in ('C','H','M','F','I','N','K','Z') THEN DO;
if POS in ('21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28') then POS_new=31;
if POS in ('86') then POS_new=32;
if POS in ('81','82') then POS_new=34;
('61','62','63','64','65','66','67','68') then POS_new=54;
END;

if Record_type = 'Encounter'and ENCOUNTER_TYPE_H054 in ('I') THEN DO;
if BILL_TYPE_CODE_1_2 in ('21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28') then POS_new=31;
if BILL_TYPE_CODE_1_2 in ('86') then POS_new=32;
if BILL_TYPE_CODE_1_2 in ('81','82') then POS_new=34;
if BILL_TYPE_CODE_1_2 in ('61','62','63','64','65','66','67','68') then POS_new=54;
END;
```

/***************************   SQL code *************************** /

```
UPDATE ALL_INPT
SET POS_new = 
     WHEN Record_type = "Claim" and Claim_Type_E0141 in ('C','H','M','F','I','N','K','Z')
          THEN CASE 
                WHEN POS in ('21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28')
                       THEN '31' 
                WHEN POS in ('86')
                       THEN '32' 
                WHEN POS in ('81','82')
                       THEN '34' 
                WHEN POS in ('61','62','63','64','65','66','67','68')
                       THEN '54' 
                ELSE POS
           END 

     WHEN Record_type = "Encounter" and ENCOUNTER_TYPE_H054in ('I')
          THEN CASE 
                WHEN BILL_TYPE_1_2_E0394 in ('21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28')
                       THEN '31' 
                WHEN BILL_TYPE_1_2_E0394 in ('86')
                       THEN '32' 
                WHEN BILL_TYPE_1_2_E0394 in ('81','82')
                       THEN '34' 
                WHEN BILL_TYPE_1_2_E0394 in ('61','62','63','64','65','66','67','68')
                       THEN '54'
                ELSE  BILL_TYPE_1_2_E0394
           END                  
END
```

;

Comment: Don't know any SAS, but it looks like your SQL is missing the outer CASE.   Should be a CASE between "SET POS_new =" and "WHEN".

Answer (score 2):

The inner `case` is the same for both conditions.  I would simplify this to:

```
UPDATE ALL_INPT
    SET POS_new = (CASE WHEN Record_type = 'Claim' and Claim_Type_E0141 in ('C','H','M','F','I','N','K','Z') OR
                             Record_type = 'Encounter' and ENCOUNTER_TYPE_H054 in ('I')
                        THEN (CASE WHEN POS in ('21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28')
                                   THEN '31' 
                                   WHEN POS in ('86')
                                   THEN '32' 
                                   WHEN POS in ('81','82')
                                   THEN '34' 
                                   WHEN POS in ('61','62','63','64','65','66','67','68')
                                   THEN '54' 
                                   WHEN Record_type = 'Claim'
                                   ELSE BILL_TYPE_1_2_E0394
                              END)  
                        ELSE pos_new                
                   END);
```

There is no `else` clause in the SAS code.  However, if none of the conditions are met, then `pos_new`'s value is unchanged.  Your version sets the value to `NULL` (which might not make a difference if that is the original value).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I just figure out a way that it would work. But your version is more condensed. Really appreciated :D